# Import "rest_framework" could not be resolved "django-rest-framework"

Tags: python, django, api, view

I have installed the Django framework but it always shows a yellow line under it as if the project is not defined

```
Settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django_filters',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_framework.routers',
'hauptapp', 
]
```

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LQbe.jpg)

Zb Import "rest_framework" could not be resolved

When i write pip freeze find

```
Django==3.2.7
django-environ==0.7.0
django-filter==21.1
django-import-export==2.5.0
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django-mssql-backend-aad==0.2.1
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-csv==2.1.1
```

Comment: run `pip list` and check if the djangorestframework module is listed or not.

Comment: i have it 
Django==3.2.7
django-environ==0.7.0
django-filter==21.1
django-import-export==2.5.0
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django-mssql-backend-aad==0.2.1
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-csv==2.1.1

Comment: I would recommend you to use a virtual environment for your project because sometimes paths in system environment get mismatched and the modules are not read correctly.

Comment: colorama              0.4.4
Django                3.2.4
django-filter         21.1
django-mssql-backend  2.8.1
django-rest-framework 0.1.0
djangorestframework   3.12.4
isort                 5.8.0
lazy-object-proxy     1.6.0
mccabe                0.6.1
pip                   21.1.2
psycopg2              2.8.6
pylint                2.7.2
pyodbc                4.0.32
pytz                  2021.1
setuptools            52.0.0.post20210125
sqlparse              0.4.1
wrapt                 1.12.1

i have it in my virtual enviroment

Answer (score 1):

Had the same probelm, in my case, as a vscode project did the next process:

1. pip3 install djangorestframework in vscode terminal, and obtained this message:

Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (3.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=3.0 in **c:\python311**\lib\site-packages (from djangorestframework) (4.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from djangorestframework) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from django>=3.0->djangorestframework) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from django>=3.0->djangorestframework) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in c:\python311\lib\site-packages (from django>=3.0->djangorestframework) (2022.7)

As you can see it says it's already satisfied in **c:\python311**, so

2. in vscode, ctrl + shift + p
3. choosed the one with the same path, in my case:
   **Python 3.11.0 64-bit C:\Python311\python.exe**

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. Here is how I fixed it:

1. In your VScode press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. Type `Python interpreter` -> select interpreter -> click on `Enter interpreter path` -> click on `Find`. This will allow you to select a Python interpreter from your machine.
3. Go to your project folder -> your virtual env folder -> `scripts` -> select `python.exe` and you're done.
4. Restart your VScode.